# Call to undefined method App\Student::contains() in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, collections, laravel-collection

In my blade view, it is giving me an error Call to undefined method App\Student:: contains()

my controller

```
if($auth->user()->getRoleNames() == '["Parent"]'){
    $id = $auth->user()->Parents_id;
    $parent = ParentName::find($id);
    $student = $parent->students;
    $announce = AnnounceMent::get();
    $roletype='parent';
    return view('announcement.index',compact('student','roletype','announce')); 
 }
```

my view file

```
@foreach($announce as $ann)
    @if($student->contains('id', $ann->student_id))
        <tr>
            <td>{{$i}}</td>
            <td>{{$ann->announcement_type}}</td>
            <td>
                <?php $course = \App\Course::find($ann->course_id) ?>
                {{$course->course_name}}
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php $student = \App\Student::find($ann->student_id) ?>
                    {{$student['firstname'].' '.$student['lastname']}}
            </td>
            <td>{{$ann->description}}</td>
            <td>
            <a class="btn btn-success" href='{{ url("viewannounce/{$ann->id}") }}'>View</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@php($i++)
@endforeach
```

this is my collection I am getting dd($students)

Collection {#595 ▼

#items: array:3 [▼

```
0 => Student {#596 }
1 => Student {#597 }
2 => Student {#598 }
```

]
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains` is a collection method, you are calling it with a non-collection, if it will be `App\Student::all()->contains('something')` it will work fine, but `App\Student::find(1)->contains('something')` or `App\Student::contains('something')` will not work

Tinker results

```
>>> App\User::find(1)->contains('email')
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App/User::contains()'
>>> App\User::all()->contains('email')
=> false
>>> App\User::contains('email')
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App/User::contains()'
>>>
```

You can do

```
$student->id == $ann->student_id
```

in your situation, I guess.

Comment: thank for replying, but I am using a collection and it is not working

Comment: @matheenulla Can you please post `dd($student)` ?

Comment: @matheenulla  and in your conditional you have ’$student’ not’$students’ notice missing ‘s’

Comment: @matheenulla if that solved your issue, consider accepting it as solution.